# Casting object into a type saved in a variable

Tags: c#, types

I have a class that operates on objects that come from external API, and extracts information from them with different procedures based on their type (in the following example, these types are `Body2`, `Face2`). I am using overloaded functions for this:

```
static class InfoExtractor
{
    public static InfoProperty Extract(Body2 body)
    {
        //...
    }

    public static InfoProperty Extract(Face2 face)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Due to the nature of that API, it is impossible to extract the type of these objects (at this point are all of type `object`), so their type is saved in a wrapper:

```
class Body2Wrapper : ApiObjectWrapper
{
    object objectRef;
    Type objectType = typeof(Body2)
}
```

(`ApiObjectWrapper` is an interface that allows me to put different implementations of it in a single list)

Finally, I have a list of `ApiObjectWrapper`, and as I iterate through it, I want to call `InfoExtractor.Extract()` with the correct overload based on the `ApiObjectWrapper.objectType`. So ideally it would be something like this:

```
foreach (ApiObjectWrapper apiObject in apiObjects)
{
   InfoProperty info = InfoExtractor.Extract((apiObject.objectType)apiObject.objectRef);
   //...
}
```

The idea here is that I would cast the `apiObject.objectRef` to whatever type was saved in `apiObject.objectType`, so that the correct overload function of `InfoExtractor.Extract` would be called. But it doesn't seem to work like this.

What is the correct way to cast that object into the type that I saved in a variable?

EDIT: I know that normally one would use polymorphism for this, but I can't because I can't change these underlying types, and I would really like to avoid saving the types of these objects in a string, and then having a `switch` to check these types and write explicit casts, like this:

```
switch (apiObject.objectType)
{
   case "Body2":
      InfoProperty info = InfoExtractor.Extract((Body2)apiObject.objectRef)
      break;
   case "Face2":
      InfoProperty info = InfoExtractor.Extract((Face2)apiObject.objectRef)
      break;
}
```

Comment: A cast requires that you know the type at compile time. `Type` is when you only know the type at runtime. These are incompatible. You're probably going to have to write some wrapper types (possibly using code generation if there's a lot of them).

Answer (score 0):

While you could easily use reflection to solve this, that is probably inefficient.

One option is to keep a list of possible overloads as `Func<ApiObjectWrapper, InfoProperty>` delegates in a Dictionary. Each delegate itself knows how to cast to the right type and call the correct fuction, you just need to get the delegate out of the dictionary.

```cs
static class InfoExtractor
{
    static Dictionary<Type, Func<ApiObjectWrapper, InfoProperty>> ExtractFuncs = new {
        { typeof(Body2), apiObject => Extract((Body2)apiObject.objectRef) },
        { typeof(Face2), apiObject => Extract((Face2)apiObject.objectRef) },
    };

    public static InfoProperty ExtractFromWrapper(ApiObjectWrapper apiObject)
    {
        if(!ExtractFuncs.TryGetValue(apiObject.objectType, out var func))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Object Type");

        return func(apiObject);
    }

    public static InfoProperty Extract(Body2 body)
    {
        //...
    }

    public static InfoProperty Extract(Face2 face)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do

```cs
foreach (var apiObject in apiObjects)
{
    var info = InfoExtractor.ExtractFromWrapper(apiObject);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast - that would require the object to be of that type. If they are object, then a cast will not work. Cast works if you have a typed obejct and STORE it in an object variable - and then take it out. But the object must be the correct type.

You can transform, in a method (possibly using automapper), into a type you return.

This is a general problem with many API - especially external, especially JSON based, where the type is depending on some parameters that the serializer can not easily pick up. What I generally do in this case is to deserialize into one object with all properties, then after analysis go down into a more specific object that is returned from my API wrapper.